# Cannot convert value of type '[RuntimeIntent]' to expected argument type '[Intent]'

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to implement Watson Conversation API in my iOS app. While passing response.intents and response.entitities to to issueCommand function, I get an error "Cannot convert value of type '[RuntimeIntent]' to expected argument type '[Intent]'". I tried to typecast both the arguments of issueCommand arguments but it wasn't useful. It will be great if someone can guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

The code is as follows:

```
func conversationRequestResponse(_ text: String) {
    let failure = { (error: Error) in print(error) }
    let request = MessageRequest(input: InputData.init(text: text), context: self.context)
    self.conversation?.message(workspaceID: Credentials.ConversationWorkspaceID,
                               request: request,
                               failure: failure) {
                                response in
                                print(response.output.text)
                                self.didReceiveConversationResponse(response.output.text)
                                self.context = response.context
                                 var entities: ConversationV1.RuntimeEntity

                                /// An array of name-confidence pairs for the user input. Include the intents from the previous response when they do not need to change and to prevent Watson from trying to identify them.
                                // issue command based on intents and entities
                                print("appl_action: \(response.context.json["appl_action"])")
                                self.issueCommand(intents: response.intents, entities: response.entities)
    }
}

func issueCommand(intents: [Intent], entities: [Entity]) {

    for intent in intents {
        print("intent: \(intent.intent), confidence: \(intent.confidence) ")
    }
    for entity in entities {
        print("entity: \(entity.entity), value: \(entity.value)")
    }

    for intent in intents {
        if intent.confidence > 0.9 {
            switch intent.intent {
            case "OnLight":
                let command = Command(action: "On", object: "Light", intent: intent.intent)
                sendToDevice(command, subtopic: "light")
            case "OffLight":
                let command = Command(action: "Off", object: "Light", intent: intent.intent)
                sendToDevice(command, subtopic: "light")
            case "TakePicture":
                let command = Command(action: "Take", object: "Picture", intent: intent.intent)
                sendToDevice(command, subtopic: "camera")
            default:
                print("No such command")
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The errors can be seen in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUOT0.png)

Comment: **Please don't screenshot your code.** Include it in your answer as a code sample.

Comment: @the4kman updated!

Comment: I have the same Problem.

Comment: Mike has written a Answer with applies to the new documentation Which can be found here:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#send_message For me it worked his solution hit, I have still other problems with other changes in the API and the realization in Swift. Example: MessageRequest(input: text, context: self.context) *Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'InputData?'*

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the signature of `issueCommand` to take `RuntimeIntents` and `RuntimeEntities`, like so:

```
func issueCommand(intents: [RuntimeIntent], entities: [RuntimeEntity]) {
```